# Retrieve list of packages from unbootable Ubuntu 15.04 installation

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, 15.04, external-hdd

How can I get a list of packages installed (excluding dependencies) on an Ubuntu installation that I cannot boot into?

Something like [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/181544) `aptitude search '~i!~M'` but reading packages from an external HDD on which Ubuntu 15.04 is installed.

Comment: Dependencies are packages too, sure you want them excluded?

Comment: Yes. I will use the list to help me install software for a new 16.04 installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by knudfl in 2010 on http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/getting-list-of-installed-packages-from-a-dead-system-811288/ can still help you:

1. mount the disk of the dead system (e.g. on /media/disk )
2. grab the list of installed programs:

   ```
   ls /media/disk/var/lib/dpkg/info/ | grep list
   ```